# Two statements in one query

Tags: sql

I want to select these pieces of information with 1 query and a subquery. How could I mix these  statements?

```
SELECT 
    name, movie_id, type
FROM
    Movie, Oscar
WHERE 
    rating = 'G' 
    AND type = 'BEST-PICTURE' 


SELECT * 
FROM Oscar 
WHERE year IN (SELECT MAX(year) FROM Oscar)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: so what would be the proper way of replacing it?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM Movie m INNER JOIN Oscar o ON m.MovieId = o.MovieId WHERE....` - or whatever column "connects" the Movie and Oscar tables .... right now, you have **NO** join condition at all - so you're combining **every single row** from `Movie` with **every single row** from `Oscar` - a classic cartesian product .... is that really what you're looking for??

Comment: Showing two statements and asking how to mix them is way too little information. As mentioned, the first statementent is likely to produce a result you don't want even. Instead tell us what the combined query is supposed to do. You can show sample data and the expected result in order to illustrate what you want to achieve.

Comment: And always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using. Otherwise you may get answers that don't work for you. In standard SQL we would typically get the latest Best Picture movie using a `FETCH FIRST ROW` clause. But does your DBMS support this clause?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to get all the oscars from the most recent year?

Without you showing us your table structures, I'm just *guessing* here - try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    m.name, m.movie_id, m.type
FROM
    Movie m
INNER JOIN
    Oscar o ON m.Movie_Id = o.Movie_Id
WHERE 
    m.rating = 'G' 
    AND m.type = 'BEST-PICTURE' 
    AND o.Year = (SELECT MAX(Year) FROM Oscar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a Subquery, which is like 2 statement in one query.